# Get the parents from a json where string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this:

```
{ 'Payment' : {
   'Referenced' : 'referenced payment',
   'Conciliate' : 'conciliate payment',
   'Multiple' : 'multiple payment'
  }
}
```

but can change in all moment for random nodes or add more, like:

```
{ 'Payment' : {
   'Referenced' : 'referenced payment',
   'Conciliate' : 'conciliate payment',
   'Multiple' : {
       'mult1' : 'example1',
       'mult2' : 'example1'
  },
  'Inventory' : {
     'datastorage' : 'dt1'
  }
}
```

All nodes can be asigned randomly, and I need to search by value, I can pass:

```
referenced payment
```

and need:

```
Payment/Referenced
```

or I send:

```
example1
```

and I need:

```
Payment/Multiple/mult1
```

I don't know if exist something like that.

Comment: I've removed the tags `reactjs` and `json` tags because neither are relevant to this question. Please share your attempt to creating a solution so we can help you figure out how to get to the answer.

Comment: `I don't know if exist something like that` no, but you can write something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// Function
const findPath = (obj, query) => {
  const makeArray = (obj, path = []) => {
    const pairs = Object.entries(obj);

    return pairs.map(([key, value]) =>
      typeof value === "object"
        ? makeArray(value, [...path, key])
        : { path: [...path, key], value }
    );
  };
  return (
    makeArray(obj)
      .flat(Infinity)
      .find(({ path, value }) => value === query)?.path.join("/") ?? null
  );
};


// Usage
const path1 = findPath(
  {
    Payment: {
      Referenced: "referenced payment",
      Conciliate: "conciliate payment",
      Multiple: {
        mult1: "example1",
        mult2: {
          test: 123,
        },
      },
      Inventory: {
        datastorage: "dt1",
      },
    },
  },
  123
);


const path2 = findPath(
  {
    Payment: {
      Referenced: "referenced payment",
      Conciliate: "conciliate payment",
      Multiple: {
        mult1: "example1",
      },
      Inventory: {
        datastorage: "dt1",
      },
    },
  },
  "referenced payment"
);

console.log("123: " + path1);
console.log("referenced payment: " + path2);
```

**Explanation**

The first step is converting the object into a linear array of the object tree and its paths. This is done recursively. Then, the array is flattened in order to be iterated through with `Array.prototype.find`, if the value matches the query, the path is returned, if no match was found it returns `null`.

**Credits**

Thanks to @Bravo for suggesting path array instead of template literal

Comment: Really nice, I searched about what you implemented, I didn't know some functions like flat, or how u use find, really thanks a lot for that, I understand all

Comment: Nice, though, personally I hate template literals - and would have makeArray like `(obj, path = []) => Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => typeof value === "object" ? makeArray(value, [...path, key]): { path: [...path, key], value });` ... and done `?.path.join('/')??null`  in the return :p

Comment: @Bravo I don't agree with hating template literals but in this case, you're right, an array makes more sense. I updated my answer and credited you.

Comment: @Undo ... I meant no real hate towards them - just that in this case I think arrays are cleaner looking code for this - I was in the process of writing a very similar answer, using array for path, and your answer beat me by about a minute